# Extract links from specific table

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I have a html code with many html tables. I want to extract links from specific one which has specific div above.

Here's my sample code:

```
        <div class="boxuniwersal_header">Table 1</div>
        <img src="img/boxuniwersal_top.gif" width="210" height="18" alt="" style="margin-top: 5px" />
        <div class="boxuniwersal_content">
          <div class="boxuniwersal_subcontent">
            <div class='menu_m1'><table cellpadding="3"><tr><td><a href="http://link.com"><img src="some.jpg"  width="45" /></a></td><td><a href="http://link.com">Some text</a></td></tr></table></div>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /box  -->

        <!-- box  -->
        <div class="boxuniwersal_header">Table 2</div>
        <img src="img/boxuniwersal_top.gif" width="210" height="18" alt="" style="margin-top: 5px" />
        <div class="boxuniwersal_content">
          <div class="boxuniwersal_subcontent">
            <div class='menu_m1'><table cellpadding="3"><tr><td><a href="http://link2.com"><img src="some2.jpg"  width="45" /></a></td><td><a href="http://link2.com">Some text2</a></td></tr></table></div>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//div/div/table/tr/td/a|//table//tr/td//a"); //querying domdocument
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $links[]=$result->getAttribute("href");
}
```

This code returns all links. I want to grab only links from Table1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is just tuning the XPath expression to select the right XML.

If you change your XPath to

```
//div[text()="Table 1"]/following-sibling::div[1]//table//a
```

What this does is first find the `<div>` element whose text is the one your after.

The `following-sibling::div[1]` part will look at the first `<div>` element at the same level as the `<div>` element already selected (this is the one where the `<table>` is).

The last part just looks for all `<a>` elements within the enclosing `<table>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this code return empty array.

Comment: Can you check you are using `$results = $domXPath->query('//div[text()="Table 1"]/following-sibling::div[1]//table//a'); //querying domdocument` as I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Now it works. I had ```div[text()=\"Table 1\"]```  instead of ```//div[text()="Table 1"]```
I had one extra question. There are 2 same links between <tr>. Is it possible to grab only one?thank you in advance

Comment: May I suggest that you use `array_unique($links);` after the loop.  This will remove duplicates.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I fixed it with in_array()  :)  Thank you for your help!